# using VMWare Player 5, how can I access a web server running in a VM via an external machine?

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

Win7 PC running Rails in an Ubuntu VM via VMWare Player. I'm working on a site and would like to show it to a friend who's outside my network.

I found this blog post, which got me very close: http://blog.fardad.com/2012/06/vmware-player-and-custom-nat-port-map.html

OK, so I have the VM that is using NAT. As I understand it, that means that the VM will appear to have the same IP address as the parent machine to outside traffic.

I went into NAT settings and added port forwarding:

```
Host Port: 8200 Type: UDP Virtual IP Address: 192.168.198.184:3000
```

OK so my understanding is that I should now be able to go to 192.168.1.1xx:8200 (the IP of my 'real' PC) and access the webserver running in the VM. But when I go to that address, I don't get anything. I can ping 192.168.198.184 (the VM) from the PC.

What I want to be able to do is go into my router and set up a port that will eventually forward into the VM.

It seems like I'm missing something very small but I don't know what that is. Help, please.

---

If anyone is curious how to get the Virtual Network Editor:

> go to the vmware-directory and run in elevated cmd.exe-box
>
> rundll32.exe vmnetui.dll VMNetUI_ShowStandalone
>
> http://communities.vmware.com/message/2155960#2155960

Comment: Is port 8200 on your host machine's firewall open? Is there a reason why you don't simply set VMware to use bridged networking instead of NAT?

Comment: It wasn't, but I opened it and nothing changed. I could use Bridged but it's all working (except this part) as is and I'm not sure I want to change it without good reason. My understanding is that this is possible with NAT. Do you think it'd be a lot easier with Bridged?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Find the `vmnetnat.conf` file, usually located in

   ```
   C:\ProgramData\VMware\vmnetnat.conf
   ```

   or

   ```
   C:\Users\Application Data\VMware\vmnetnat.conf
   ```
2. Edit `vmnetnat`, add similar line in the `[incomingtcp]` section

   ```
   8200=192.168.198.184:3000
   ```
3. Restart `VMware NAT Service`.

Comment: These options are documented here: https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-C2EC7B92-A499-4B47-95B6-0BFDDA28AC34.html

Comment: `vmnetnat.conf` does not exist

Answer (score 6):

Try using Bridged network option in vmware player instead of NAT. It replicates your physical network.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an http proxy to do that, by doing that you don't need to expose your entire private network, check out this blog post for more information [how to access docker containers from external devices](http://blog.nunes.io/2015/05/02/how-to-access-docker-containers-from-external-devices.html)